# Cannot hide the underlying div with opacity set to 1

Tags: css

This is what I see right now.

[image]

What I would like to see is that the div with text 'Top' should totally eclipsed the 'Under' div.

Here is my code ([available in codepen](http://codepen.io/kongakong/pen/MKzmMm)):

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  init();
});

function init() {
  $('input').on('click',
    function () {
      $('.answer').addClass('textout');
    });
}
```

**css**

```
.row {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}


.answer {
  width:100%;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 100;
}

.answer-new {
  position: absolute;
   /* border: 1px solid blue;*/
   width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.textout {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(1000px);
  transition: transform 2s ease-in;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="contrainer">
  <div>
    <input type='button' value="test"></input>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="answer-new">Under

    </div>
    <div class="answer">Top
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

My question:

Is `opacity` the right way to hide another div in this situation? What is the right approach? I want to keep the 'Under' div visible because the css transform is supposed to achieve  a 'reveal' effect

Comment: 3 css ways to let an element invisible: `opacity:0; visibility:hidden; display:none;` The difference is that on `display:none` the object totally disappears while in the others even invisible they keep holding their place/space on the page layout.

Comment: Thanks. But my question is not about make element invisible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying `background` property to `.answer` element satisfy your needs?

```
.answer {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: red;
  width:100%;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 100;
  background:#fff;
}
```

## EDIT

If you don't know the background of your container or it is not a solid color, then you can play with `width:0` and `overflow:hidden` for that matter, like here: http://codepen.io/prowseed/pen/rxQwbQ

Comment: Just wonder if you have a quick answer: my background colour is assigned in runtime. How can I get the css to pick up the inherited background colour?

Comment: Well, if it is assigned in runtime, then you can assign bg color to that div as well :) But anyway I will update my post with better answer in a minute

Answer (score 2):

You could give the above div a background colour to hide the div underneath until it slides away.

**Or**

You could give the underlying div an opacity of 0 and fade it in upon reveal.

See updated [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPOXod)

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  init();
});

function init() {
  $('input').on('click',
    function () {
      $('.answers').addClass('textout');
    });
}
```

CSS

```
.row {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}


.answer {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: red;
  width:100%;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 100;
}

.answer-new {
  font-size: 40px;
  position: absolute;
   /* border: 1px solid blue;*/
   width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
}
.answers.textout .answer-new {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 400ms 200ms ease-in;
}

.answers.textout .answer {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(1000px);
  transition: transform 2s ease-in;
}
```